# I get a types error when registering redis with nestjs using CacheModule.register

Tags: redis, nestjs

I am trying to implement redis using the packages : "CacheModule" and "cache-manager-redis-store". The latter brings me a type error when assigning it to the store property of the register method of CacheModule.

code where the error occurs:

`

```
import { Module, CacheModule } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { EnvConfiguration } from "./config/env.config";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { redisStore } from "cache-manager-redis-store";
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [EnvConfiguration],
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB),
    AuthModule,
    CacheModule.register({
      store: redisStore, <--- HERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
      host: "localhost",
      port: 6379,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`

ERROR:
`

```
(property) store: (string | CacheStoreFactory | CacheStore) & ((config: RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts> & Config) => Promise<...>)
Cache manager. The default value is 'memory' (memory storage). See Different Stores for more information.

Type '(config: RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts> & Config) => Promise<RedisStore>' cannot be assigned to type '(string | CacheStoreFactory | CacheStore) & ((config: RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts > & Configuration) => Promise<...>)'.
  Type '(config: RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts> & Config) => Promise<RedisStore>' cannot be assigned to type 'string & ((config: RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts> & Config) => Promise<...>)'.
    Type '(config: RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts> & Config) => Promise<RedisStore>' cannot be assigned to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

`

I want to be able to implement redis with nestjs, solving the described problem or with another way of implementing it that works correctly.

Comment: Did you find a proper solution to this problem. I have encountered the same issue and the answers have not really helped. I am getting around it by type casting like this `imports:[CacheModule.register( { store: redisStore as unknown as CacheStore ...` but it feels a little too hackie

Comment: nevermind I've discovered that this solution has issues too. But there is an alternative solution at https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/issues/40, it is to use `cache-manager-redis-yet` instead of `cache-manager-redis-store`

Answer (score 7):

cache-manager v5 not compatible with NestJS till now so 
Just use this versions:

```
"cache-manager": "^3.6.0",
"cache-manager-redis-store": "^2.0.0",
```

Comment: It's almost september 2023,but this is the only solution worked for me. Go to your `package.json` change the above properties, hen delete `node_modules`, run `npm i` and `npm run build`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out this github link
https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/issues/40

To sum up for you, they will use `cache-manager-redis-yet` instead of `cache-manager-redis-store`

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation properly-
cache-manager-redis-store does not support redis v4. In order for the ClientOpts interface to exist and work correctly you need to install redis 3.1.2 major release.

and go to app.module.ts file add RedisClientOptions (import this from redis, import type { RedisClientOptions } from 'redis') CacheModule.register ({})

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
A little feedback on making it even more helpful: can you edit it and format the code that you are suggesting for the import? You can find the formatting guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) . Please also consider removing the opening comment "Read documentation properly": it will be more likely for your help to be better received without that. Thanks again, your contribution is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```js
import { redisStore } from "cache-manager-redis-store";
```

to this:

```js
import redisStore from "cache-manager-redis-store";
```

or this:

```js
import * as redisStore from "cache-manager-redis-store";
```

or this:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const redisStore = require("cache-manager-redis-store");
```

Answer (score -1):

The method of importing `redisStore` is the problem. The location pointed out as the issue is where the error is being generated.

From [Nest JS Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#different-stores)

```js
import type { ClientOpts } from 'redis';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { CacheModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register<ClientOpts>({
      store: redisStore,

      // Store-specific configuration:
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: ok but when importing redis it gives me the following error message: The module '"redis"' does not have any member 'ClientOpts' exported

Comment: can you check what redis you have installed, name and version from your package.json.

Comment: either ways, that a type and it can work without importing client options and not passing it in `CacheModule.register<ClientOpts>`